# Minizinc : how to check if a row exists in an 2D array

Tags: minizinc

I have an 2D array like that :

```
array[1..3,1..3] of var 1..3: t;
```

how can I write a constraint to check if there is a table row that matches |1,2,3| (for example) ?

I wrote it like that but it doesn't work that return a type error :

```
constraint [1,2,3] in t;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to **check** that `[1,2,3]` is in `t`:

```
array[1..3,1..3] of var 1..3: t;
var bool: check;

constraint
  exists(i in 1..3) (
    t[i,..] == [1,2,3] 
  ) <-> check
;
```

Some solutions:

```
...
t = 
[| 3, 2, 3
 | 3, 3, 3
 | 3, 3, 3
 |];
check = false;
----------
t = 
[| 1, 2, 3
 | 3, 3, 3
 | 3, 3, 3
 |];
check = true;
----------
t = 
[| 2, 1, 2
 | 3, 3, 3
 | 3, 3, 3
 |];
check = false;
----------
...
```

If you want to **ensure** that `[1,2,3]` is in `t`, you can skip the `check` variable:

```
array[1..3,1..3] of var 1..3: t;
constraint
  exists(i in 1..3) (
    t[i,..] == [1,2,3] 
  )
;
```

Some solutions:

```
t = 
[| 1, 2, 3
 | 3, 3, 3
 | 3, 3, 3
 |];
----------
t = 
[| 1, 2, 3
 | 2, 3, 3
 | 3, 3, 3
 |];
----------
t = 
[| 1, 2, 3
 | 1, 3, 3
 | 3, 3, 3
 |];
----------
...
```